# Issues installing angular2-meteor with npm

Tags: npm, angular, npm-install, angular2-meteor

Trying to start a new angular2-meteor project using

```
npm install angular2-meteor --save
```

Get a whole bunch of red errors (below) and I am not sure what they mean. I have already done 
`npm install npm -g`

 and 

`npm update -g`

Here's the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you followed the Quick Start [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor).

**angular2-meteor** package has not been exposed to NPM yet. 
Check [this issue](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/167)

**UPDATE:**

Refer [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor) and [here](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/180) for latest tutorial.

Now you can install, follow these steps:

1. Update your meteor globally (If you already updated, then no need to do it again. And go [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/releases) to check if there is a new version).

   `meteor update --release 1.3-rc.4`
2. Run these in your terminal to create an angular2-meteor1.3 project:

   `meteor create --release 1.3-rc.4 hello`

   `cd hello`

   `npm install https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor --save`

   `npm install https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap --save`

   `meteor remove blaze-html-templates`

   `meteor add angular2-compilers`
3. Remove **main.js**, **main.html**, **main.css** files in the client folder.
4. Then create these two files in your client folder:

**// app.ts**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap'
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<p>Hello World!</p>`
})
class App {}
bootstrap(App);
```

(Make sure you put `import 'reflect-metadata';` first line before other import, otherwise it won't work.)

**// index.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<app></app>
</body>
```

At last, run `meteor` in the terminal and go to `http://localhost:3000` to check your app.

Comment: Thanks @Hongbo Miao, that makes a lot more sense now. I suppose with angular2 being in beta many packages haven't caught up yet.

Comment: @ahetman now you can create a angular2-meteor 1.3 project, just follow the steps.